# Cerrar Ventana JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy intentando hacer que la ventana actual se cierre mediante algún tipo de función java script. Pero no he conseguido lograrlo. Ya he usado algunos métodos pero al parecer no funcionan a menos que la ventana sea abierta por medio de una función similar, algo que no viene al caso.

```
function Finalizar() {        

  var ventana = window.self;
  ventana.opener = window.self;
  ventana.close();

}

function Finalizar() {        

  parent.window.close();

}

function Finalizar() {        

  setTimeout("self.close();", 7000);

}

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="self.close();">Entendido</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript:self.close()" >Entendido</button>
```

Este es el mensaje que obtengo al debugear el explorador

```
Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.
```

¿Algo de información para ayudar al problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si quieres que la ventana actual se cierre solo usa esto:

```
window.close();
```

Y listo no tienes que hacer nada mas, el codigo que quieres usar es cuando tienes un parent o abriste algun popup desde una ventana padre.

Solo usalo asi:

```
function Finalizar() {        
    window.close();
}

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="Finalizar();">Entendido</button>
```

Comment: bastante útil, era el método que faltaba probar, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Los scripts de javascript sólo pueden cerrar las ventanas que ellos mismos han abierto: [Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

Comment: Creo que esta es la mejor respuesta. Sin embargo, también creo que se podría beneficiar mostrando el código... Por más que sea 1 sola línea, fijate que el autor no está del todo orientado en cómo cerrarla, por lo que ayudaría a que sea una respuesta completa y de calidad.

Comment: muchas gracias por comentarlo, creo que es muy útil para quien presenta un problema similar.

Answer (score 0):

Ya desde la última especificación no es posible, como medida de seguridad, a menos que cumplas una serie de condiciones detalladas en https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/browsers.html#dom-window-close